# Fatal error, is this because of host?

Tags: errors, memory

Suddenly I am getting the following error on my website, I don't know why, but I think this is because of shortage of RAM or Memory in the host?
Is it true?

Error:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated
>   12845056) (tried to allocate 311296
>   bytes) in
>   /wp-content/plugins/WPRobot3/wprobot.php(1239)
>   : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1)
>   : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1)
>   : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1)
>   : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1)
>   : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code on
>   line 335
>
> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated
>   18874368) (tried to allocate 35 bytes)
>   in /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1140

Is this because of insufficient memory with the host? or is it because of wp?

Notices

```
Notice: get_settings is deprecated since version 2.1! Use get_option() instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3237

Notice: register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3237

Notice: register_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_widget_control() instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3237

Notice: register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3237

Notice: register_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_widget_control() instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3237

Notice: register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3237

Notice: register_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_widget_control() instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3237

Notice: register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3237

Notice: register_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_widget_control() instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3237

Notice: register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3237

Notice: register_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_widget_control() instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3237

Notice: register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3237

Notice: register_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_widget_control() instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3237

Notice: Undefined index: page in wp-content/plugins/seo-booster-lite/seo-booster.php on line 980

Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3321

Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3321

Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3321

Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3321

Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3321

Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3321

Notice: Undefined index: page in wp-content/plugins/autoblogged/autoblogged.php on line 164

Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3321

Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3321

Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3321

Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3321

Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3321

Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3321

Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3321

Notice: Undefined index: page in wp-content/plugins/seo-booster-lite/seo-booster.php on line 990
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is clearly out of memory error, it seems to be caused by obfuscated code in plugin's file.

There is rarely legit reason to run that many layers of [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) so either that code is obfuscated for not-so-good reason or some error is causing endless loop (which should trigget another error by exceeding recursion, but possibly memory runs out before that).

Comment: @Rarst but I am using this plugin from long back no error I ever faced, and second thing, this is not the same, some times I also get on other files like, pluggable.php, load.php etc

Comment: @ntechi if you are getting errors with eval in different files and especially WP core files - I'd strongly suspect that you were hacked. If it is out of memory errors you should try [inscreasing memory limit](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP).

Comment: @Rarst how to know that my website is been hacked? and in my wp-config I have allocated 256 MB, and one more thing from last 1 day in my FTP also I am facing problems regarding with memory allocation, thats why I thought its due to hosting?
How can I solve this?

Comment: @ntechi ask your hosting to check, if probability you are indeed hacked is high, well - Otto has it right in [How to Cope with a Hacked Site](http://ottopress.com/2011/how-to-cope-with-a-hacked-site/).

Comment: You can also see eval errors when running plugins like "exec php" and similar, since these plugins will often eval code.

Comment: @Rarst @t31os I am also getting notices, if I am enabling `wp_debug`, what does that means, check my question for notices

Comment: They mean exactly what they say, you have some code running(plugin/theme/custom code) that is executing deprecated functions, arguments or not checking an array index is set before using it.

Comment: @t31os But I didn't modified any code, it was not even touched, is my site hacked?

Comment: You see notices when you enable debug mode, it's normal to see them when active, normally you'd not be aware of plugins/themes/custom-code running old functions(etc..) because the notices are surpressed.

Comment: @t31os so that is something I don't have to worry about it?
am i rite? and why suddenly it popped out?

Comment: @ntechi - Like i said, you see those notices because you've enabled debug. Whether or not you should worry is a matter of whether you trust these plugins, i personally don't trust a developer who can't do something as simple as check array indexes are set, eg. `if( isset( $var['key'] ) )`.. (i'm no expert myself, but this is basic PHP, its lazy to ignore such simple things).